# What do fields in Django-tastypie do?

Tags: django, tastypie

What is the point of defining fields in a tastypie resource? I read the documentation

> When designing an API, an important component is defining the
>   representation  of the data you’re presenting. Like Django models, you
>   can control the  representation of a Resource using fields. There are
>   a variety of fields for  various types of data.

What does it mean by, "defining the represenatation"?

Comment: Please provide a link to the documentation, so that we can see the quote in context.  I suspect that if you read a little further, the meaning of the quoted paragraph will become clear.

Comment: http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fields.html @RobertHarvey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One key aspect of [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) is that you change application state via *representations* and not directly, like e.g. in RPC-style systems. The representations are then exchanged in various formats (JSON, XML, you name it), which need to be specified (be it for you or your API audience). As I understand it, you can specify this in tastypie via `Resource` classes and their *fields*:

- https://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fields.html?highlight=fields

Just as an untested dumb example, let's define a Resource:

```
class PersonResource(Resource):
    name = fields.CharField(attribute='name')
    hats = fields.IntegerField(attribute='number_of_hats', null=True)
```

Then a JSON serialization could look like:

```
{ "name" : "miku", "number_of_hats" : 14 }
```